# Why can't I filter on IS NOT NULL in this query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to filter NULL results in my query but it is giving me an error.

My query:

```
SELECT
  cnt.id,
  cnt.title,
  cnt.introtext,
  cnt.fulltext,
  cnt.ordering,
  cnt.images,
  cnt.alias,
  cnt.state,
  f.item_id,
  MAX(CASE
    WHEN f.field_id = 3 THEN f.value
  END) AS inslider
FROM snm_fields_values f
JOIN snm_content cnt
  ON cnt.id = f.item_id
WHERE cnt.state = 1
AND f.value = 'ja'
AND inslider IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY f.item_id
ORDER BY f.item_id, inslider
```

This query gives me:

> Unknown column 'inslider' in where clause.

`inslider` is the row that returns a null value, when I remove the IS NOT NULL line from the above query, my result is:

[image]

( I know an image is bad instead of text but I couldn't get it formatted nicely on SO. )

How can I filter a result if it returns NULL on `inslider` (which is an alias).

Comment: The WHERE clause is evaluated before the SELECT list.

Comment: Try HAVING clause instead for that condition.

Comment: you cannot use alias in WHERE clause

Comment: are you sure MAX(CASE
    WHEN f.field_id = 3 THEN f.value
  END) AS inslider is correct?